# Examples of mobile broadcasts being used

Tags: cell-broadcast

I recently found this page of settings in on my phone under Cyanogenmod, I had never even heard of this system before.

[image: mobile broadcast settings]
<sup>mobile broadcast settings (click to enlarge)</sup>

Are there any examples of this system being used in the past?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/157567/9897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  They're called [Wireless Emergency Alerts](https://www.fema.gov/emergency-managers/practitioners/integrated-public-alert-warning-system/public/wireless-emergency-alerts) in the USA. The underlying standardized technology is called [cell broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast), and is part of the telecommunication standards your phone supports.

The system is not without problems: There was [a thing in California](http://www.networkworld.com/community/blog/california-amber-alert-shows-atts-emergency-alert-system-be-mess) in 2013 over the first use of the system giving utterly irreverent information (sending the alert to people hundreds of miles from the event), presumably due to poor implementation.

Comment: Ah, I see it's an American system, that's why I had probably never even heard of it living in the UK.

Comment: No, it is not only American system. I have seen it being used in Baltics (Europe). See http://android.stackexchange.com/q/157567/9897

Comment: Lithuania has used that system during the COVID-19 pandemic, e.g. to inform people about restrictions entering into force. However, this does not seem to work on CyanogenMod/LineageOS.

Comment: @user149408: In general it does work on LineageOS (it's been part of core Android / AOSP since Android 11). But there are many things that can go wrong...

Comment: @sleske yes, Android has the functionality, but I have two devices running different versions of CM/LOS which didn’t display anything on several occasions when my company iPhone got an alert. Others have noted this as well, seems this is indeed broken in LOS, see https://gitlab.com/LineageOS/issues/android/-/issues/3667.

Comment: @user149408: Hm, I also have a LOS device, which did receive the warning sent out in Germany today. Strange.

Comment: @sleske would you mind adding the version and device to the ticket I linked above? Might help narrow down the issue.