# Why to get Mobile Broadcast notices in OxygenOS 3.x abroad?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, oneplus-two, cell-broadcast, oxygenos

I am abroad and get such notices about [cell broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast) etc when in Baltics in Fig. 1. My SIM card settings are in Fig. (2-3). 
Fig. 1 Broadcast-notice visible often in Baltics, 
Fig. 2 Settings > SIM Cards > Sim Card 1, 
Fig. 3 Settings > SIM cards > Sim card 2

[image]
[image]
[image]

I googled the *[city] 14442* but could not find anything about it. 
Perhaps, it is some piece of information about radio channels but could not find about it. 
Some threads recommend to configure Call Settings ([here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/97076/9897) thread *Turning off cell broadcast in HTC Desire 816*).
To turn them off in OxygenOS, you can go to *Settings > More > Mobile Broadcast settings* > choose there appropriately.

- Turn off *Amber* alerts.

OS: OxygenOS 3.1 (Android 6.x)
Phone: Oneplus 2
Related: [Examples of mobile broadcasts being used](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/54426/9897), [Turning off cell broadcast in HTC Desire 816](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75540/9897)

Comment: My guess would be the provider announces the [Cell Broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast) channel that way. Check [these posts](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=cell+broadcast) for more details.

Comment: @Izzy Yes, I think you are right. I cannot find any Call Settings in OxygenOS, see the body.

Comment: Masi, that got nothing to do with *call* settings. It's the cell broadcast channel you have to select in the cell broadcasts app (if your device has any). A little Google-Fu turned up [this thread](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/cell-broadcast-on-oneplus-2.444122/). Quoting: *Go to settings/Wireless & Networks/More/Emergency Broadcasts.* (that's where you at least can turn them off). You can also check for an app named "cell broadcast" – or see the second link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 6 feature in some regions. I have not get them in default Android 7 anymore.